# Modification on Boyer Moore Algorithm to find an element that occurs more than n/3 times

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, divide-and-conquer

Given an array of numbers with length $n=3^k$, we try to find an
element that occurs more than $\frac{n}{3}$ times. So work as follow:

> We divide the array into 3 parts of equal length. Find
> recursively a candidate $x$ in each partition and do a scan on
> array to find number of occurrence of each candidate and then
> return the candidate with the maximum number of occurrence.

Can we claim that algorithm above work correctly? What is running time of this idea?

I think this is a version of  [Boyer Moore Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_majority_vote_algorithm) that divides our input into three sections. But I can't prove that. Also I think this algorithm runs in $O(n\log n)$ time because
$T(n)=3T(\frac{n}{3}) +O(n)=O(n\log n)$.

Comment: If that's your intended running-time, wouldn't it be simpler if you just sort the array then scan it to find the element that appears more than $n/3$ times?

Comment: No, I try to analysis my idea.

Comment: With *aab bbb baa ccb ddb eeb aab bbb baa*, what do I get? Which candidates do I scan for, and how did they become candidates?

Comment: @jhjhb This recursive approach is very different from Boyer–Moore algorithm.